# Как правильно настроить права для ftp пользователя и веб сервера

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ftp, apache2.4

Здравствуйте.
Установил и настроил lamp на vds сервер, все отлично работает. Так же установил vsftp.

Есть пользователь `user`, он имеет доступ по фтп только к своей папке. Когда загружаю файлы, то владельцем становится `user`, и группа `user`. Когда из админки пытаюсь загрузить изображения, то происходит ошибка что у сервера нет прав и он не может созлдавать директории. Назначил папке куда загружаю изображения пользователя и группу `www-data`, и все отлично создается и загружается. Но теперь через ftp не удаляется ничего.
Вопрос в том, как совместить что бы и с фтп можно было удалять и загружать файлы, и сервер спокойно создавал и загружал файлы

Comment: традиционный комментарий: [пожалуйста, перестаньте насиловать труп ftp](https://pasztor.at/blog/dont-use-ftp-heres-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сделать `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/files/` для каталога с файлами.
2. Юзеру `user` сделать основную группу `www-data`: `usermod -g www-data user`
3. Перелогиниться на ftp, проверить доступность записи/модификации/удаления данных.

ps по этой схеме все будет ок, если веб-сервер и ftp создают директории по маске 775, файлы - 664. Если же нет, то надо будет заставить их это делать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сделал все как вы сказали, но всеравно через фтп не удалются файлы. Команда: DELE favicon.ico
Ответ: 550 Delete operation failed.

Comment: А как заставить их это сделать?

Comment: @TrueKanonir Посмотрите с какими правами создает директории и файлы Апач, потом тоже самое проделайте для ftp и напишите сюда.

Comment: Это папка drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 11 15:24 112 это фаил -rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 42568 Apr 11 15:24 84.jpg

Comment: @TrueKanonir я так понимаю - это созданное веб-сервером? А ftp какие права выдает?

Comment: да, это созданное веб сервером. А вот загруженное через фтп: папка `drwxr-xr-x 10 user www-data   4096 Apr 10 23:25 app`, фаил `-rw-r--r--  1 user www-data 1198 Apr 11 13:47 helpers.php`

Comment: @TrueKanonir для `vsftp` сделайте в конфиге `local_umask=002`. Рестарт vsftp и снова пробуйте - должно получиться 775 (директории) и 664 (файлы). Для убунтовского Апача можно в файл `/etc/apache2/envvars` добавить строчку umask 002. Рестарт Апача.

Comment: Все сделал. Так же ерунда...

Comment: Спасибо вам за уделенное время. Решил оставить как есть. Только папке с картинками сделал владельца и группу `www-data`, а остальным владеет `user`

Comment: @TrueKanonir смотрите сами. Но вариант с конфигурацией ftp и Апача рабочий.