# Linux: файл записывается с правами 600

Tags: linux, permissions, права-доступа

Есть сайт, апач и nginx работают под www-data. Есть пользователь ftp, он грузит файлы в подпапку сайта. Сделал пользователя ftp членом группы www-data, но почему-то файлы, которые загружаются через него, имеют права 600 (только для этого пользователя), соответственно, для www-data они недоступны. Как сделать так, чтобы все файлы, загружаемые пользователем ftp были доступны и его группе?

Comment: почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/812581/288358 и может быть надо будет менять маску

Comment: А как пользователь ftp загружает файлы? Через FTP-клиент? Если так, то FTP-сервер должен быть сконфигурирован нужной маской.

Comment: Пользователь выгружает файлы из 1С. То есть это все-таки надо в общем и целом править на стороне выгрузки?

Comment: Править надо на стороне того процесса, который выполняет непосредственное создание файла в нужной папке (а из вашего описания пока что не очень понятно, какой конкретно процесс это делает и в чём связь между 1С и ftp)

Comment: тогда надо посмотреть юзера/группу, кто создал файл. `getfacl файл`

Comment: Решение нашлось. Достаточно было прописать гостевого юзера в vsftpd, www-data, теперь все записывается от его имени